# How can I run a script on keyboard power key press with systemd?

Tags: systemd, logind

I have a power key on my keyboard, and I want to run a script when it's pressed.

I looked around and didn't found anything on this, for what I've seen, people always have been satisfied with what *logind.conf* is offering, here is the interesting part of *man logind.conf*:

```
HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=, HandleLidSwitch=, HandleLidSwitchDocked=
       Controls how logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or suspend. Can be one of "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock". If "ignore", logind will never handle these keys. If
       "lock", all running sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the
       "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.  HandlePowerKey= defaults to "poweroff".  HandleSuspendKey= and HandleLidSwitch= default to
       "suspend".  HandleLidSwitchDocked= defaults to "ignore".  HandleHibernateKey= defaults to "hibernate". If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if
       more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs; otherwise the HandleLidSwitch= action occurs.

       A different application may disable logind's handling of system power and sleep keys and the lid switch by taking a low-level inhibitor lock
       ("handle-power-key", "handle-suspend-key", "handle-hibernate-key", "handle-lid-switch"). This is most commonly used by graphical desktop environments to take
       over suspend and hibernation handling, and to use their own configuration mechanisms. If a low-level inhibitor lock is taken, logind will not take any action
       when that key or switch is triggered and the Handle*= settings are irrelevant.
```

I didn't managed to set bold text in code block (and didn't used quote block since it puts all in a single line and it then clearly unreadable), I then repeat the interesting part here:

> Controls how logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or suspend. Can be one of
>              "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock".

Or I am in the wrong way and this is just for keyboard keys, and not power button ?

In any case, previously, it was easy with acpi, one just had to replace the *power_button* script in */usr/lib/acpid/*, isn't there something equivalent for systemd ?

Thanks.

PS: [How to change Power button shutdown action to run a script under systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555822/how-to-change-power-button-shutdown-action-to-run-a-script-under-systemd) suggested in comments does not answer my question, as I answered this is to manage power key from keyboard, not power button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Power button shutdown action to run a script under systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555822/how-to-change-power-button-shutdown-action-to-run-a-script-under-systemd)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not, this is, as many answers I found on the subject, to manage power key from keyboard, not power button...

Comment: what is the difference of `powerKey` and `powerButton`?

Comment: @gluttony I think you want to capture a button press on your keyboard rather than than the ACPI power button. If I have got this the wrong way round please re-[edit] your question to make absolutely clear what it is you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @roaima, since my question has been marked as duplicate I've done what stackexchange suggested me, i.e. ask a new question, this is what I did here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563603/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-on-power-button-press-with-systemd

Comment: @αғsнιη: power key is on the keyboard, power button is the computer power button, I edited the new question I posted about this (because of duplicate) with an image: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563603/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-on-power-button-press-with-systemd

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this question is no more set duplicate, I then opened another one for which I found an answer (for openbox at least), since I don't know how to set duplicate I just put the link to the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566910/390900